# Why should I use thread-specific data?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

Since each thread has its own stack, its private data can be put on it. For example, each thread can allocate some heap memory to hold some data structure, and use the same interface to manipulate it. Then **why thread-specific data is helpful**?

The only case that I can think of is that, each thread may have many kinds of private data. If we need to access the private data in any function called within that thread, we need to pass the data as arguments to all those functions, which is boring and error-prone.

Comment: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2121

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike the stack (which, like thread-local data is dedicated to each thread), thread-local data is useful because it persists through function calls (unlike stack data which may already be overwritten if used out of its function).

The alternative would be to use adjacent pieces of global data dedicated to each thread, but that has some performance implications when the CPU caches are concerned. Since different threads are likely to run on different cores, such "sharing" of a global piece of data may bring some undesirable performance degradation because an access from one core may invalidate the cache-line of another, with the latter contributing to more inter-core traffic to ensure cache consistency.

In contrast, working with thread-local data should conceptually not involve messing up with the cache of other cores.

Comment: Just declare it at the top of the run/execute function or, if OO, in the thread class instance.

Answer (score 4):

Thread-local storage is a solution for avoiding global state. If data isn't shared across threads but is accessed by several functions, you can make it thread-local. No need to worry about breaking reentrancy. Makes debugging that much easier.

From a performance point of view, using thread-local data is a way of avoiding *false sharing*. Let's say you have two threads, one responsible for writing to a variable *x*, and the other responsible for reading from a variable *y*. If you were to define these as global variables, they could be on the same cache line. This means that if one of the threads writes to *x*, the CPU will update the cache line, and this of course includes the variable *y*, so cache performance will degrade, because there was no reason to update *y*.

If you used thread-local data, one thread would only store the variable *x* and the other would only store the variable *y*, thus avoiding false sharing. Bear in mind, though, that there are other ways to go about this, e.g. cache line padding.

Comment: I think what you've mentioned here is similar to Blagovest Buyukliev's words? Then how about allocating all thread private data on the stack, compared to thread-specific data? Is there any difference when taking the cache or other low-level mechanism into consideration?

Comment: @PJ.Hades: allocating all the thread-local data on the stack could be wasteful if the data is not reasonably small.

Comment: @PJ.Hades: Yes, what Blagovest Buyukliev said about cache performance is what I'm saying. Automatic storage (the stack) is only available per function. If you wanted the data to persist across functions, you'd have to pass the data as an argument, which could worsen performance. You could allocate it on the heap and pass a pointer, but if only a few functions use it while you are passing to several, it'll get ugly, especially if there are many variables that need to be passed.

Answer (score 2):

Think of thread local storage as another kind of global variable. It's global in the sense that you don't have to pass it around, different code can access it as they please (given the declaration of course). However, each different thread has its own separate variable. Normally, globals are extra bad in multithreaded programming bacause other threads can change the value. If you make it thread local, only your thread can see it so it is impossible for another thread to unexpectedly change it.

Another use case is when you are forced to use a (badly designed) API that expects you to use global variables to carry information to callback functions. This is a simple instance of being forced into a global variable, but using thread local storage to make it thread safe.

Comment: '(badly designed) API that expects you to use global variables to carry information to callback functions' - this drives me mad! Anyone who sets up a callback without alowing an eatra pointer/whatever for user data should be strung up.  TLS is not even much use here either - often, the setter-upper wants to supply a different pointer/object for every callback.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I've been writing multithreaded apps for 30 odd years and have never, ever found any need to use TLS.  If a thread needs a DB connection that the DB binds to the thread, the thread can open one of its own and keep it on the stack.  Since threads cannot be called, only signaled, there is no problem.  Every time I've ever looked at this magic 'TLS', I've realized it's not a solution to my problem.

With my typical message-passing design, where objects are queued in to threads that never terminate, there is just no need for TLS.

With thread-pools it's even more useless.

I can only say that using TLS=bad design.  Someone put me right, if you can :)

Comment: TLS is the right thing to use if it fits the problem it solves. In your solution, you have complete control over the DB handle and the code using it, so passing it around as arguments to parameters works fine. You don't always have complete control over other code, so you may have to devise workarounds, TLS might be useful in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

I've used thread local storage for database connections and sometimes for request / response objects. To give two examples, both from a Java webapp environment, but the principles hold.

A web app might consist of a large spread of code that calls various subsystems. Many of these might need to access the database. In my case, I had written each subsystem that required the db to get a db connection from a db pool, use the connection, and return the connection to the pool. Thread-local storage provided a simpler alternative: when the request is created, fetch a db connection from the pool and store it in thread-local storage. Each subsystem then just uses the db connection from thread-local storage, and when the request is completing, it returns the connection to the db pool. This solution had performance advantages, while also not requiring me to pass the db connection through every level: ie my parameter lists remained shorter.

In the same web app, I decided in one remote subsystem that I actually wanted to see the web Request object. So I had either to refactor to pass this object all the way down, which would have involved a lot of parameter passing and refactoring, or I could simply place the object into Thread Local storage, and retrieve it when I wanted it.

In both cases, you could argue that I had messed up the design in the first place, and was just using Thread Local storage to save my bacon. You might have a point. But I could also argue that Thread Local made for cleaner code, while remaining thread-safe.

Of course, I had to be very sure that the things I was putting into Thread Local were indeed one-and-only-one per thread. In the case of a web app, the Request object or a database connection fit this description nicely.

Comment: Downvote if you disagree, but please explain why. I'm also trying to learn here!

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but the problem with your answer is that it's not very clear, and it doesn't seem relevant. You've just mentioned how caching connections can improve performance, but that has nothing to do with thread-local data. Your reasoning about passing the connection as an argument to a function isn't correct either. Provided you pass by pointer, there is no extra overhead (using thread-local data also involves indirection).

Comment: @craigmj I didn't downvote either. But I care more about the use and advantages of thread-specific data, compared with the normal stack storage of the private data. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add on the above answers, that as far as I know, performance wise, allocation on stack is faster than allocation on heap. 
Regarding passing the local data across calls , well - if you allocate on heap, you will need to pass the pointer / reference (I'm a Java guy :) ) to the calls - otherwise, how will you access the memory? 
TLS is also good in order to store a context for passing data across calls within a thread (We use it to hold information on a logged on user across the thread - some sort of session management).

Answer (score 0):

Thread Specific Data is used when all the functions of a particular thread needs to access one common variable. This variable is local to that particular thread but acts as a global variable for all the functions of that thread.

Let's say we have two threads t1 and t2 of any process. Variable 'a' is the thread specific data for t1. Then, t2 has no knowledge over 'a' but all the functions of t1 can access 'a' as a global variable. Any change in 'a' will be seen by all the functions of t1.

Answer (score 0):

With new OOP techniques available, I find thread specific data as irrelevant.  Instead of passing the function to the thread, you can pass the functor. The functor class that you pass, can hold any thread specific data that you need.

Eg. Sample code with C++11 or boost would like like below

```
MyClassFunctor functorobj;       <-- Functor Object. Can hold the function that runs as part of thread as well as any thread specific data
boost::thread mythread(functorobj);



Class MyClassFunctor
{
private:
 std::list mylist; <-- Thread specific data
public:
    void operator () ()
    {
      // This function is called when the thread runs
      // This can access thread specific data mylist.
    }
};
```